# Sharing any Network Connection starts a connection/disconnection loop

Tags: 11.10, network-manager, sharing

Am trying to Share an internet connection to another PC. I have tried doing it wirelessly and wired. Both ways when trying to share it connects and disconnects several times until failing to connect at all. It repeats this a couple of times and then just drops. If I try to connect again it does the same pattern again.

My PC has an Intel card which receives the Internet connection. Another wired card, a Realtek shares this connection to another PC.

Same goes for a Broadcom and a Ralink wifi cards. I tried both of them to share a Wifi connection with no such luck (Both installed and already working to connect to anybody). They of course connect but they do not share. This, all of this worked perfectly on 11.04.

What could be the problem for all network interfaces not been able to share a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was solved after updating Ubuntu with the latest weekly updates. After October 20th, all problems related to sharing a Wifi/Wired are gone. Works perfectly.